# localStorage + jQuery autosave and load p

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 1;

    $("button").click(function() {
        var inputVal = $('input').val();
        $('div').append("<p>"+ inputVal +"</p>");
        localStorage.setItem('pvalue'+count, inputVal);
        $("input").replaceWith("<input id='num_" + count++ +"'/>");
    })

    var local = localStorage.getItem("pvalue"+ count);
    $('div').append("<p>"+ local +"</p>");

})
```

This code saves **all** values of input but shows only **first**. I dont know how to display all saved p tags after refresh, can anybody help me?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class='mt-5 text-center'>
        <input> <button>Add</button>
    </div>

    <script src='script.js'></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to your use of the `count` variable. This is fine when setting the data, however when re-loading it `count` will be set back to `1` and you won't explicitly know how many entries you've saved.

A much better idea would be to store an array in localStorage which you can easily add to and retrieve. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {    
    var inputVal = $('input').val();
    $('div').append("<p>" + inputVal + "</p>");    

    var pValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pvalue')) || [];
    pValues.push(inputVal);
    localStorage.setItem('pvalue', JSON.stringify(pValues));
  })

  var pValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pvalue')) || [];
  var html = pValues.map(function(local) {
    return '<p>' + local + '</p>';
  }).join('');
  $('div').append(html);
})
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If you need it, here's a working example in a fiddle as SO doesn't allow localStorage access in snippets: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/8q6ewbgL/